# how to hide the small fat32 drive that is for linux UEFI bootloader, from Windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning, multi-boot, manjaro

I've dual booted my Windows 10 OS with a Manjaro Linux distribution. While installing the Manjaro, I was asked to create a 500mb fat32 partition for the UEFI boot and I was warned that without it, bootloader might not work at all. So I created that partition.

Now I have booted back into my Windows OS and because Windows recognizes FAT32, the 500mb drive is there in my computer among my other drives and it's annoying, is there a way to hide it without causing any problems? I don't want to lose my Manjaro bootloader.

Comment: Didn't Windows already have its own EFI partition?

Comment: @grawity Do you mean I don't need to create another one for Manjaro and it will be fine? I read somewhere else too that Windows has an EFI partition itself but I don't find any EFI folders in my C: drive(I'm certain that my windows is using UEFI boot).

Comment: Well, they're not in your C: drive _because_ they're in a different partition. (The "C:" letter corresponds only to a single partition, not to the whole disk.) Normally Windows doesn't show its own EFI partition, though you can access it with `mountvol /s`. And yes, if the existing EFI partition has enough free space, you can just reuse it for Linux alongside Windows.

Comment: @grawity Great! Thanks. It has almost 200mb free space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the direct answer is (well, should be) to set the 'Hidden' and 'Do not automount' flags on the partition using `gdisk` or a similar tool.

1. Run `gdisk /dev/sda` (if that's your disk)
2. In main menu, use `p` to see the partition list
3. In main menu, use `x` to enter the expert menu
4. In expert menu, use `a` to change attributes, and enter your partition's number
5. In the attribute list, enable "62" (hidden) and "63" (do not automount) attributes
6. In expert menu, use `w` to write changes and exit.

And the indirect answer is **you don't need the partition.** One disk only needs a single EFI system partition, and multiple operating systems can share it.

1. Mount the Windows EFI partition somewhere temporary, e.g. `/mnt/winefi`;
2. Move the Mint EFI files to the Windows EFI partition (retaining the same folders etc.)
3. If Mint uses GRUB2, run `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/winefi`;
4. Reboot and see if it worked. If it did, delete the now-empty Mint EFI partition.

Comment: Thanks once again, I like the first way better, because a Windows update might overwrite the EFI partition.

Comment: It never does. In the design of EFI (which Microsoft participates in), the whole reason of having a partition is that the OS _wouldn't_ need to overwrite everything; it'd just have its own `\EFI\<vendor>` subfolder.

Comment: That's good that you can hide it in OS, but I for example want to hide whole disk from windows, so malware won't be able to mess with linux files

Answer (score 0):

You could unhide the fat32 partition on a basic disk with DiskPart:

- Input `cmd` into Windows search box to open the Command Prompt.
- Then type `diskpart`.
- Type `list disk` command to list all your hard disks in the computer.
- Input `select disk n`, where is `n` is the number of the hard disk
  that the fat32 partition on it.
- Type `list partition` to show all the partitions on the selected
  MBR/GPT hard disk.
- Type `select partition m`, where `m` is the number of the
  fat32 partition.
- Then type `assign`  the system will assign a drive letter
  automatically.

After these commands, you can see the fat32 partition in Windows Explorer.

If you want to **hide** it, basically the same as the steps of unhide, the only different is the **last step**.

- type `remove letter=e`, the `e` is the drive letter of the fat32
  partition.